# Tools to check file presence and integrity after installation

Tags: tools

I have different versions of different programs, that require different sets of files/resources. Knowing a list, I would like to check after the installation of a software, that all the corresponding files are present in some folders.
This list would be an XML file, or a .properties or whatever. Checking the file integrity, with a checksum for example, would also be awesome.

Is there an existing tool for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple C# app would help to solve most of the things you have mentioned

- Read from input XML, file name and the expected path and report results for file existence
- Same Approach - Read folders / programs that need to be checked for their existence
- Other custom needs that you have mentioned - file integrity, with a checksum can also be achieved

I would prefer writing these utilities as it is a great way to learn coding / as well customized for your need

Comment: After a lot of research, it seems to be to best way indeed. I already know how to code, I was just too lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

Most test automation tools can check for the presence of a file within a designated folder.

I use WinTask. It can accomplish that task easily.